# extract data from a dictionary column to R dataframe

Tags: r, json, regex

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

| Rest of data frame | columnToSeparate |
| --- | --- |
| blablarow1 | {"info1":"row1string1","info2":"row1string2"} |
| blablarow2 | {"info1":"row2string1","info2":"row2string2"} |

What is the best way to extract this information as separate columns in my dataframe to get something like:

| Rest of data frame | info1 | info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blablarow1 | row1string1 | row1string2 |
| blablarow2 | row2string1 | row2string2 |

Here is code to create the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(RestOfDF  = c("blablarow1", "blablarow2"),
                 columnToSeparate = c('{"info1":"row1string1","info2":"row1string2"}',
                                      '{"info1":"row2string1","info2":"row2string2"}'))
```

**Update:** My real column has lots of infoN fiels, so I am looking to do something as automatic as possible as the names are actually different. Something like
{"mydogsname":"pinky","mycatsfood":"icecream"...}

Answer (score 4):

I think this can also help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  magrittr::extract(1) %>%
  bind_cols(str_extract_all(df$columnToSeparate, "(\\w+\\d+)(\\w+\\d+)", simplify = TRUE) %>%
              as_tibble() %>%
              setNames(c("info1", "info2")))

    RestOfDF       info1       info2
1 blablarow1 row1string1 row1string2
2 blablarow2 row2string1 row2string2
```

Answer (score 3):

Clean the `columnToSeparate` column removing unwanted text (i.e remove `["{}]`), split text into different rows by splitting on comma (`,`) and in different columns by splitting on colon (`:`). Use `pivot_wider` to get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(columnToSeparate = gsub('["{}]', '', columnToSeparate)) %>%
  separate_rows(columnToSeparate, sep = ',') %>%
  separate(columnToSeparate, c('col1', 'col2'), sep = ':') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2)

#  RestOfDF   info1       info2      
#  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      
#1 blablarow1 row1string1 row1string2
#2 blablarow2 row2string1 row2string2
```

Comment: Dear Ronak, would you please explain a little bit about your regex in first line, and in particular why you use `[` for that. It's amazing but I can't figure out how it matches all the `"` and `{`.

Comment: All the characters inside `[]` is matched and removed using `gsub`. So here it removes `"`, `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. So since `{` is a metacharacter, we don't need to escape it inside `[ ]`?

Comment: Yes, as we are using `[]` we don't need to escape it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough dear Ronak. Thanks indeed.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` & `stringr` solution:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  # get rid of metachars:
  mutate(columnToSeparate = gsub('[\\"{}]', '', columnToSeparate)) %>%
  # extract `info1` using lookbehind and lookahead:
  mutate(info1 = str_extract(columnToSeparate, "(?<=:)[^,:]+(?=,)")) %>%
  # extract `info2` using lookbehind and lookahead:
  mutate(info2 = str_extract(columnToSeparate, "(?<=:)[^,:]+(?=$)")) %>%
  # remove obsolete column:
  select(-2)
    RestOfDF       info1       info2
1 blablarow1 row1string1 row1string2
2 blablarow2 row2string1 row2string2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `columnToSeparate` is in JSON format. So, we can

1. use the `fromJSON()` function from the `jsonlite` package to parse the data,
2. use `rbindlist()` from the `data.table` package to create a data.frame with separate columns,
3. and join this intermediate result with the original `df` as requested.

```
setDT(df)[, rbindlist(Map(jsonlite::fromJSON, columnToSeparate), 
                      fill = TRUE, idcol = "columnToSeparate")][
                        df, on = "columnToSeparate"][
                          , columnToSeparate := NULL][]
```

> ```
>          info1       info2       info4   RestOfDF
> 1: row1string1 row1string2        <NA> blablarow1
> 2: row2string1 row2string2        <NA> blablarow2
> 3:        <NA>        <NA>        <NA> blablarow3
> 4:        <NA>        <NA> row4string4 blablarow4
> ```

Note that a modified dataset has been used to cover additional edge cases as the OP has mentioned that "the names are actually different".

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(RestOfDF  = paste0("blablarow", 1:4),
                 columnToSeparate = c('{"info1":"row1string1","info2":"row1string2"}',
                                      '{"info1":"row2string1","info2":"row2string2"}',
                                      '{}',
                                      '{"info4":"row4string4"}'))
```

Rows 1 to 2 are taken from OP's original dataset.
Row 3 has no data.
Row 4 has only one data item and uses a different name.